# Group low frequency counts in to a single 'other' category

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, categories

Apologies if there is a very simple solution to this problem. I am new to R and data handling in general.

I have a dataset with a number of factors, and counts associated with them. For instance,

```
A 25
B 1
C 15
D 5
E 2
```

My end goal here is to create a pie chart using the data frame. I want to include all the values, but to group the values below a certain count/percentage in to a new category, or an 'Other' category. For instance, if the threshold was 5:

```
A 25
C 15
Other 8
```

I am able to group my data that is above a certain threshold using the `subset()` function, but this only returns the higher values I want to use in a new table, and I cannot work out how to add the exluded values in to an 'Other' category in a new data frame.

If anyone can assist me I would greatly appreciate it. There have been one or two similar posts in the past on this subject, but all were either not quite the same situation, or very difficult for me to follow along with.

Thanks for your time!

Image of data:

[image: HERE]

Comment: Try `i1 <- df1$Col2 < threshold; df1$Col1[i1] <- "Other"; aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, df1, sum)` (assuming 'Col1' is `character` class)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Col1 I believe may be a factor? To get the data frame I am using, I have taken tidy data and grouped by name and then used the tally() function to get the counts. I have tried your solution and got this error message: 'In '[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i1, value = c(NA, NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated'.

Apologies for my slowness, I am not very familiar with R.

Comment: You can check my solutions below.  the `forcats` method would also work for `factor`

Comment: If you want the base  R solutiion to work `levels(df1$Col1)[levels(df1$Col1) %in% df1$Col1[i1]] <- "Other"` and then use the `aggregate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to collapse the `factor` levels or `character` is using `fct_collapse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
threshold <- 7
out <- df1 %>% 
         count(Col1 = fct_collapse(Col1, Other = unique(Col1[Col2 < threshold])),  
            wt = Col2)
out
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Col1      n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        25
#2 Other     8
#3 C        15
```

then, we can create a pie chart

```
library(ggplot2)
out %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n, fill = Col1)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

[image]

#### Update

Based on the OP's dput, we can change the column names to the OP's column names

```
df2 %>%
  count(Haplogroup = fct_collapse(as.character(Haplogroup), 
      Other = unique(as.character(Haplogroup)[n < threshold])),
      wt = n, name = "n1")
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Haplogroup    n1
#  <fct>      <int>
#1 Other         40
#2 E1b           14
#3 N1a           12
#4 R1            10
#5 R1a           15
#6 R1b           25
```

---

Or another option is `base R` (assuming the column is `character` class), create a logical vector by comparing the 'threshold' with 'Col2', assign the elements in 'Col1' where the 'i1' is TRUE to 'Other', then do a group by `sum` with `aggregate`

```
i1 <- df1$Col2 < threshold
df1$Col1[i1] <- "Other"
aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, df1, sum)
#    Col1 Col2
#1     A   25
#2     C   15
#3 Other    8
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Col2 = c(25L, 
1L, 15L, 5L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I cannot express enough how grateful I am for you to take the time to work through this with me, so thank you very much. If you have the time at some point, I would also be quite interested to know how the code fits together and what each part relates to in creating the final product. Totally understand if you'd rather not at this point though!

Comment: @RightSo Glad to know that it works. In the `forcats`, code, we are converting the `Haplotype` column to `character`, then we create a logical vector (`n < threshold`) within the `count` and. that is used to subset the `Haplotype` elements i..e if `v1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9); threshold <- 5; `v2 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')` with subsetting we do `i1 <- v1 < threshold` (instead of creating an object) `v2[i1]` and specify the `unique` elements in 'Other' i.e. `Other = unique(v2[i1])` while we specify `wt` as 'n' so as the get the weighted count or `sum`.  In effect values from v2[i1] are 'Other'